# What does closing the socket do in the following code

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm learning the `sockets` python module and I'm looking at the following tutorial code:

```
'''
    Simple socket server using threads
'''

import socket
import sys
from thread import *

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    #Sending message to connected client
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n') #send only takes string

    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:

        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        reply = 'OK...' + data
        if not data: 
            break

        conn.sendall(reply)

    #came out of loop
    conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

I'm stuck on the final line, `s.close()`. I don't understand what this does since the code seems to be stuck in an infinite loop right above, which is never broken. Am I missing something or is `s.close()` totally extraneous in this instance?

Comment: You see the `break`?

Comment: @Klaus D. Doesn't the `break` within the function `clientthread` only break out of the while loop within the function? It doesn't break out of the main thread while loop - `while 1`, no?

Comment: Yes, the final `close()` is redundant and will not be reached.

Comment: My guess is that a previous version of the program included a way to break out of the while-loop, or perhaps the author planned to include such a mechanism but forgot to implement it.  In that case, the `s.close()` would free the socket's resources.